# Smooth width transition with a calligraphic brush stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I know that Illustrator does not allow the use of width tool or a variable width profile for a stroke/path made with a calligraphic brush. I am looking for alternative ways of producing the same effect.

First, let me show you what I am trying to achieve. Excuse the crude WIP graphics:

[image]

So, I have this cassette tape. Two strands of tape will come out and wrap around other objects and eventually the remaining strand expand in size and break into pixels. I am looking for a way for the last 15-25% of the strand to start expanding in width, kinda like that:

[image]

The first line is where I would like the tape to start smoothly expanding, to the size shown at the end.

To give you more info: The tape is made using the pen tool with the Illustrator default 5 pt. flat calligraphic brush from the brush definition menu. I can technically achieve the expanding effect by hand, but it will be hard to keep it really smooth and make it more difficult to modify the shape afterwards (which I would like to keep). Is there a way I can achieve this effect without making the shape by hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With any other brush you'd simply use the width tool... unfortunately you can't use it on calligraphic brushes

Comment: Yeah, I wish there was a way of making a ribbon shape from a path quickly without using the calligraphic brush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this via distort mesh:
Select tape and create mesh: Object>Envelope Distort>Make With Mesh, left default values:

[image]

Select Mesh Tool (U) and add some mesh nodes at the tape end:

[image]

Use mesh tool (U) some move mesh nodes to various directions:
[image]

Calligraphic brush  remains editable at the same time,  to edit brush itself use toolbar button 'Edit Content'

Comment: Yeah, it seems this is the best way to achieve that effect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An idea that may work for you...

Instead of a calligraphic brush, use a normal brush stroke with a Transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*). Set some movement and a number of copies to fake the calligraphic effect...

[image]

You can then use the Width Tool (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) on the original path...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the appearance of the stroke will let you edit the thickness at the end.

1. Create a calligraphic path.

[image: Calligraphic path in Illustrator]

2. Choose `Object` → `Expand Appearance` to convert the stroke to a path.

[image: Expand Appearance]

3. You can now move the points in the path, and make the edge jagged.

[image: Adobe Illustrator]

Comment: This will be my last resort, because I will lose the editable path and making a smooth width transition for the calligraphic line will require some fiddling. Nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Comment: @FredBednarski Yep. You could keep a copy of the original around. Or, you could do this to just get the end portion, then use the original for the rest (keeping it editable).